# Javascript: Replace thumbnail with original size image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm fairly new to Javascript, that being said, I have a good understanding of how Javascript works.

Basically, I'm wanting to **replace** a thumbnail image with the original size image when clicked (max-width of image to be shown).

Best example I can give is with https://4chan.org/g/ - When you click a thread thumbnail, it'll be replaced.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. You can use the width and height set for the thumbnail and reset the width and height on click.
2. You can check how to replace the img src set on the toggle button. First, set the thumbnail and on click, change to the original src URL. Next, toggle img src use the thumbnail again, and repeat the process.
Happy coding :D

Comment: AlokeT - Can you give me an example please

Comment: are you able to make the changes and make it work? @Liambalis1

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to use javascript to change the image source

```js
let thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail");
for (let i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
   thumbnails[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      let tempLink = this.src;
      this.src = this.getAttribute("data-attribute");
      this.setAttribute("data-attribute", tempLink);
  });
}
```

```html
<img class="thumbnail" data-attribute="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img/favicon144.png" src="https://yari-demos.prod.mdn.mozit.cloud/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img/favicon72.png"></img>
```

Comment: What if the full_image is a seperate source. I.E., thumbnail dir = ./thumbnail/image.jpg AND full image dir = ./images.jpg

Comment: oh in that case you should follow AlokeT's method. Instead of changing `this.class`, change `this.src`

Comment: this.srcList.toggle(FULL_IMG SOURCE);?

Comment: I have updated the code to show one way it can be done, the exact string manipulation is up to you, depending on how you name the images and thumbnails. In this case, the mdn example has one image that is 72px and a full image with 144px, so my string manipulation is simply to change 72 to 144 and vice versa

Comment: IMHO: `this.src.replace("72", "144")`, this seems so iffy... Furthermore, this will only replace the first occurrence of `72`... What if the filename already has `72` in it?

Comment: that's why I am saying the exact string manipulation is up to the user, I just found these two images on the internet that can help me explain my point

Comment: The thumbnail and original size image is in seperate directories. Is there a way to store the original size image directory in a data-attribute...

Comment: oh yeah, that is a better idea, do you know how to do that?

Comment: Not exactly no. I'm not the greatest at Javascript. But I understand the concept and it makes sense once someone shows me. That's how I learn :p

Comment: OK I have edited the code to show you how. It was a good idea that you had! This also resolves DarkBee's concern with the string manipulation.

Comment: Okay, that does work. But the thumbnail src isn't being displayed in HTML. What I'm trying to figure out is how can I replace a thumbnail image to the orignal size image. Instead of just enlarging the thumbnail.

Comment: I don't understand your point. This replaces the src of the img everytime you click on it. You can replace with whatever image you like by changing the address in `data-attribute`